# Using Array formula with countif

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've the below formula:

```
=countif(C$2:C2,"="&C2)
```

That is working will.
When I tried to use `ARRAYFORMULA` I replace the `&C2` by `&C2:C` but could not know what shall I use instead of `C$2:C2`.
The below formula is not working as I want:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(countif(C$2:C2,"="&C2:C))
```

I also tried the below, but did not work as well:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(countif(C$2:"C"&ROW(),"="&C2:C))

=ARRAYFORMULA(countif(ROW(INDIRECT("C$2"&":"&"C"&ROW())),"="&C2:C))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C:C="",,COUNTIFS(C:C,C:C,ROW(C:C),"<="&ROW(C:C))))
```

[image]

Comment: I think your title is too generic. You could probably use something like *"Using Array formula with countif to find repeated values"*. Just a thought.